Why does SignalR fail to bind arguments here?
I am working on a WPF application (the client) that invokes SignalR methods using the .NET SignalR driver like this:
private void TEST_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Global.SignalR?.InvokeAsync("Ping").Wait();
    Global.SignalR?.InvokeAsync("Ding", 123).Wait();
}

The SignalR Hub runs on a ASP.NET Core application and looks like this:
public class ChatHub(ILogger<ChatHub> logger) : Hub {
    public async Task Ping() {
        logger.LogInformation("Ping!");
        await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Pong");
    }

    public async Task Ding(int x) {
        logger.LogInformation($"Ding! {x}");
        await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Dong");
    }
}

When pressing the test button the "Ping!" message is displayed in the server debug output and shortly after the "Pong!" message is displayed in the client debug output.
Then the client throws an exception when attempting to invoke "Ding" with the message:

Failed to invoke 'Ding' due to an error on the server. InvalidDataException: Error binding arguments. Make sure that the types of the provided values match the types of the hub method being invoked.)

Instead I expected the server to output "Ding! 123" without crashing.

After enabling more debugging by adding:
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR": "Debug",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections": "Debug"

To the appsettings.json I discovered the message:

System.InvalidOperationException: Reflection-based serialization has been disabled for this application. Either use the source generator APIs or explicitly configure the 'JsonSerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolver' property.

Which turns out to be related to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/serialization/8.0/publishtrimmed
So after setting PublishTrimmed to false in the project configuration it is now working as intended. I will most likely go over to using the source generator api later, but at least I now know what the root of the issue was.
